# asp.net mvc jquery form plugin upload(file not recieved by the controller)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

i am using jquery form plugin for file upload . i am not able to get file in the controller . what could be wrong.

```
    public string CreateOrganizationMeta()
    {
        foreach (string file in Request.Files)
        {
            HttpPostedFileBase postedFile = Request.Files[file];
        }
```

}

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $('#MyForm').ajaxForm({

     });      
 });


      <% using (Html.BeginForm("Organization", "CreateOrganizationMeta", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "MyForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data", onsubmit = "return submitForm2(this)" }))
     { %>
        <input type="file" name="Logo2" id="Logo2" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can upload files using ajax. There are some workarounds for this though.

Try googling for [file uploads with ajax](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&source=hp&q=file+uploads+with+ajax&btnG=Google+Search&aq=f&aqi=&aql=&oq=file+uploads+with+ajax&gs_rfai=&fp=9707303a2bce8ea3)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for this plugin states that it supports file uploads.

I've used Andrew Valums' [Ajax Upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/) on several projects and it works great.  May be an alternative to consider.